# Improve Java code to be executed faster on Android

Tags: java, android, performance

My Java code is executing really slowly in my Android device. I think it's because I made it all in one class. I need some recommendations for how to improve my code, maybe by dividing it into different classes. How you would do it?

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    View white;
    Animation downtoup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Remove notification bar
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        //MovingScanSquare
        white = findViewById(R.id.white);
        downtoup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.downtoup);

        white.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        downtoup = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.1f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.f);
        downtoup.setDuration(2200);
        downtoup.setRepeatCount(-1);
        downtoup.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        downtoup.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        white.setAnimation(downtoup);


        //movingscreen
        final ImageView backgroundOne =  findViewById(R.id.background_one);
        final ImageView backgroundTwo =  findViewById(R.id.background_two);

        final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, -1.0f);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(3000L);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                final float progress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                final float width = backgroundOne.getWidth();
                final float translationX = width * progress;
                backgroundOne.setTranslationX(translationX);
                backgroundTwo.setTranslationX(translationX + width);
            }
        });
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Splitting the code in several classes could improve readability, but I fail to see how it would improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the code into different classes won't get you so far. And it's quite difficult to say what's going on there without profiling it. Use one of the profiling tools, [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) for example, to do that.

Monitor your application, find out which line of code takes too much time and try to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

To improve readability you can use different classes. But it will not improve performance much.

For long processing task use background thread instead of doing it on the main thread.